# Strange output in my Python script - [0m or [32m

Tags: python, string, bash, file, colors

I am using wpscan in my Python script and saving the result in a file.

Unfortunately, I get in my output numbers like `[0m` or `[32m`. 
I read that this is the option for different colors, 
how can I avoid it, so that the string in my file doesn't get this strange numbers/words?

Comment: Try using the `--no-color` option to wpscan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan/#wpscan-arguments), you can pass `wpscan` the parameter `--no-color` to omit the colors.